# Assigning [NSDate date] to NSString in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, nsdate

In Objective C, we could easily assign present date to NSString like `string = [NSDate date];`.

Could someone help me how to assign the same in Swift ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17):

First off, your statement...

> In Objective C, we could easily assign present date to NSString like string = [NSDate date];

Is complete rubbish.

In Objective-C you need to use an `NSDateFormatter` to render an `NSString` out of an `NSDate`.

You would do it something like this...

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle

NSString *string = [df stringFromDate:date];
```

Now, in Swift, not surprisingly, it is EXACTLY the same.

```
let date = NSDate()

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle

let string = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

Comment: @RiyazulAboobucker I fail to see what's rude. The question of "converting" a date to a string has been asked thousands of times on Stack Overflow and the answer is always the same... and it is **never** `string = [NSDate date];`. Stating that as fact is just wrong.

Comment: upvoted cause of this part: in Swift, not surprisingly, it is EXACTLY the same

Answer (score 11):

maybe you want this:

```
let string = NSDate().description
```